# How to set multiple sequences as features in KERAS

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I want to make Named Entity Recognition model with Keras.
These are the links that I have followed:

https://valueml.com/named-entity-recognition-using-lstm-in-keras/
https://djajafer.medium.com/named-entity-recognition-and-classification-with-keras-4db04e22503d

Data looks like this:

```
                word label
0          Thousands     O
1                 of     O
2      demonstrators     O
3               have     O
4            marched     O
...              ...   ...
44187          there     O
44188   accidentally     O
44189             or     O
44190   deliberately     O
44191              .     O
```

They are using word to vectors, so they are indexing the words and labels, so that `X` are my features (index sequences of words) and `y` are my results (index sequences of labels):

```
max_len = 30
X = [[word2idx[w[0]] for w in s] for s in list_of_sentances]
X = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=X, padding="post", value=num_words-1)

y = [[label2idx[w[1]] for w in s] for s in list_of_sentances]
y = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=y, padding="post", value=label2idx["O"])
y = [to_categorical(i, num_classes=num_labels) for i in y]
```

But what if I have dataset like this:
[image]

here I have another column and that is `POS`. How can I add values of `POS` column to my features?
So basically, I do not want only `word` values in my X, i also want `POS` values in my X. *(or any other values)
What If I have multiple columns, such as:

```
word
POS
is_capital_letter
word_length
```

...

How can I add all of these columns to my features?

This is my model:
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)

print("x_train shape", x_train.shape)
print("x_test shape", x_test.shape)
#x_train shape (750, 75)
#x_test shape (250, 75)


input_word = Input(shape=(max_len,))

model = Embedding(input_dim = vocab_len+1, output_dim = 75, input_length = max_len)(input_word)
model = SpatialDropout1D(0.25)(model)
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units = 25, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout = 0.2))(model)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(num_labels, activation = "softmax"))(model)

model = Model(input_word, out)
```

Answer (score 1):

LSTM layers in Keras expect input in the dimension of [samples, timesteps, features].

- Samples are tipically independent observations. In your case I assume these are the sentences.
- Timesteps are the separate input varables given continously to the model. These should be the words in one sentences.
- Features are the separate measures for one observation, aka. features of one single word.

In the line, where **X** is created, you interate over the sentences and words and transform the "single" feature (*word*), assuming **w** contains one line from your dataset ([*word*, *label*]).

Provided you have multiple features as the first **n** columns in the dataset (and the target is the last column, e.g. *[word, POS, is_capital_letter, word_length, ..., label]*) and you have collected/defined the necessary "transform" dictionaries in **transforms** in the same order as it is in the dataset, then you can generate the input and target as follows:

```py
transforms = (word2idx, pos2idx, ...)

X = [[[transforms[i][w[i]]] for i in range(n)] for w in s] for s in list_of_sentances]
Y = [[label2idx[w[n]] for w in s] for s in list_of_sentances]
```

Of course, if you have numerical or other type of features, then you should use other approaches for tranformation than *word2idx*, *pos2idx*, ... dicts, e.g. MinMaxScaling for word length, etc.

Padding also works with the new X and Y, but it extends each feature with the same **value** for the length of **max_len**. It is very possible that elaborated padding should be used here depending on what is the subtitute value of each feature.

Comment: sorry I haven't understood you, can you please write me a more detail explanation?

Comment: I have tried your solution, but Im getting an error when I want to train my model: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_4 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (750, 75, 1, 1)